Can $K_{5,5}$ be embedded in a torus?
I know of the classic Three Utility Problem which asks if $K_{3,3}$ can be embedded in a torus, to which the answer is yes. Wikipedia states that it is also true for $K_{4,4}$. Then what about for $K_{5,5}$? I see on Wolfram Mathworld that a graph of genus $\gamma = 1$ can be embedded in a torus. Since $\gamma(K_{5,5}) = 2$, it's apparently a double toroidal graph, does that mean that it cannot be embedded in a torus? Thanks.

Per Wikipedia, “The genus of a graph is the minimal integer n such that the graph can be embedded in a surface of genus n.”

@PaulTanenbaum I'm a bit confused about the English. Does it mean that for a surface of genus $n$, all graphs of genus greater or equal to $n$ can be embedded therein?

From http://algol.acadiau.ca/~agagarin/Embeddings.pdf , I don't see $K_{5,5}$ on the list of $n=10$ graphs that embed on the torus, so at least $K_{5,5}$ doesn't embed in the genus 1 surface.

The passage I quoted from Wikipedia means that if a graph has genus g, then it can be embedded in a surface of genus g but cannot be embedded in any surface of genus less than g.
